# MacBook Air keeps crashing due to memory problem

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, memory, crash

After I installed the new macOS Catalina update, every time I finish working on a project on Eclipse, my Macbook Air crashes. The message I get after it restarts is that it is a memory problem. If I restart my Mac after using eclipse it works fine. Is there a way I can clear the memory or downgrade the OS without wiping my data? The solutions I have seen so far weren't helpful.

"sfree on invalid allocation at 0xffffff80334f36b0"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/

*** Panic Report ***

> panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff800b29d6ed): "a freed zone element has been modified in zone kalloc.16: expected 0xc0ffee9ce1a653e1 but found 0, bits changed 0xc0ffee9ce1a653e1, at offset 0 of 16 in element 0xffffff8058162cf0, cookies 0x3f00111cbfb07c00 0x53521385e1ae743"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4570 .41.2/osfmk/kern/zalloc.c:1120

Comment: Please include the actual message in your question. Do you have a backup from before you've upgraded?

Comment: I don't have a backup

Comment: There should be a lot more to the panic report than these few lines.  Can you please [edit] your question to include the full report?

Comment: Not possible to downgrade your OS directly. TimeMachine won't restore back ups to earlier versions of macOS than it was created on. You can still wipe/reinstall High Sierra, then manually restore your files.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should upgrade to a later version of Eclipse. It may be a legitimate issue that they haven't fixed yet.